# Jacobian of linear and nonlinear systems using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am writing a python class for both linear and nonlinear MIMO systems. These two classes inherit from a parent class called Model, which contains the ode of the model. For the linear system, the function looks like

```
def disc_linear_fn(x, u):
    A = np.array([[],[],[],[]])
    B = np.array([[]])
    x_dot = A @ x + B @ u
    return x_dot
```

whereas the function of a nonlinear system returns a nonlinear ode.

I want to acquire the Jacobian for both nonlinear and linear systems.

Question 1: How to acquire the exact matrices in a linear system ode function without returning them, i.e. A,B.

Question 2: Which package can be used to calculate the Jacobian of a nonlinear system in numpy. I know how to realize it by programming the approximation algorithm or using packages such as casadi, jax, sympy, but I'd prefer to not describe systems in other packages. Since the next step is to solve an optimization problem in cvxpy, I want to keep every information in numpy to maintain consistency.

Any recommendations would be appreciated! Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Expand a bit on Q1. It is unclear to me what you mean by "acquire the exact matrices".

Comment: For Q2, use https://github.com/pbrod/numdifftools

Comment: Many thanks for the comments! For Q1, this function is given into a class. I want to acquire A and B from this function without explicitly returning A, B matrices. One possible way for me is to calculate the approximate Jacobian, but the matrices in this way are approximated.

Comment: Can you just make A and B part class members? self.A, and self.B

Comment: Thy class is taking A and B in the constructor now. I posted this question since I'm trying to modify this constructor function a bit. Many thanks for the suggestions!